# Multipole Expansion Intuition

Tags: charge, dipole, dipole-moment, multipole-expansion

So my intuition of the multipole expansion is that we have a certain charge distribution, and the ME tells us that we can approximate that distribution as a superposition of monopoles, dipoles, etc. Physically we could have a certain dipole for instance, then adding a quadropole to this takes us a step closer to the original charge distribution. Repeat this an infinite number of times, adding higher order terms like octopoles, 32-poles etc and we would end up with the exact charge distribution. Correct me if I am wrong, but would this be the intuition behind ME?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. It is similar to the Fourier series where a periodic function is rebuilt using a basis of oscillating functions. The Fourier decomposition translates a periodic function of one continuous variable into a function of a discrete variable (an index).

If you consider a function of the two angles $\vartheta$ and $\varphi$, that is, a function whose argument is a direction pointing somewhere on a unit sphere, you can use the spherical harmonics as a basis. Here we have a function which is again periodic in its two variables and translate it into a function of two indices. This is used, for example, when analysing the cosmic microwave background which is described by a function $T(\vartheta, \varphi)$ giving the temperature of the background radiation depending on the direction in the night sky, you are pointing your detector at. You can get a set of coefficients $a_{lm}$ from a decomposition in spherical harmonics $Y^m_l(\vartheta,\varphi)$.

If you are interested in a function which is defined on whole $\mathbb{R}^3$, the different $l$-modes scale with some particular power of $r$. But this is specific to the particular function we are expanding, typically the function $\frac{1}{\vec r-\vec r'}$ which is the Green's function of the Laplace operator.

Comment: This Answer is in contrast with this answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/707354/102243
and this (https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/554825/102243)
Namely, the answer in combination with the question suggests that the multipole expansion will eventually contain all the information about the charge distribution. This is wrong. The Multipole approximation is an approximation that yields the right fields far away from the charge distribution, but will eventually fail at small distances even with all terms written out.