# The multipole expansion of electrostatic potential and large distances

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, approximations, multipole-expansion

I'm reading Griffiths electrodynamics book and I'm currently studying the multipole expansion of electrostatic potential, and I have two questions if you don't mind:

1. Can I use the multipole expansion if the point at which I'm measuring potential isn't far from the configuration? Or Can I just use it for very large distances?
2. What does large distance mean here? Is it just large compared to the dimensions of the charge configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No.
2. Yes.

Simple as that. The multipole expansion is an asymptotic expansion where you need a small parameter to make sure that each higher-order term you add will be (much) smaller than the one before. This is the ratio $r/R \ll 1$ of the size of the charge density $r$ and the distance to the point where you use the expansion $R$.

Comment: so what about a pure monopole or a pure dipole situated at the origin?Why is it exact then?

Comment: A pure monopole is an idealization: a point charge with no spatial extent. I.e. $r=0$ and all distances $R$ at which you use the field will be much larger than zero. Also, to see that the expansion is exact just calculate the dipole moment, quadrupole moment etc. They all vanish for the ideal monopole.

Comment: what about the pure dipole? Does it have to be at the origin also for the potential to be exactly given by the dipole term alone?

Comment: Of course not. In that case the result would depend on the choice of coordinate system. But beware: When the charge distribution is $\rho(x)=q\delta(x-a)$, of course the expansion is to be taken around the point $a$, i.e. the dipole moment is not $\int \rho(x)x\text{d}x$, but $\int \rho(x)(x-a)\text{d}x$. The first one would be nonzero, the second one, with the right choice of the center of the charge distribution, is zero, as should be expected for the ideal monopole.