# Are other terms in multipole expansion other than the monopole term always there?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

My question is whether the remaining terms other than the monopole actually always there and we consider only the monopole for convenience purposes (because it is the most dominant term) or they sometimes exist or does not exist depending on the circumstances.

That is, to get the most exact potential to a given charge configuration, we should sum the infinite number of terms from the monopole to the n-pole.
But as it is impossible to do so and most of all, monopole is the most dominant term as the other terms go to zero at a large distance, we calculate only the monopole for the potential for convenience sake.

But in the case where the charge configuration sum is zero, the monopole does not exist. So we instead start from the dipole term.

This is how I intuitively understood. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

For a system containing several charges, or a volumetric distribution of charges, yes, the multipole expansion usually goes to infinity, and it's a matter of choosing where to truncate the expansion for a given situation.

There are some special cases where some terms can be zero, forcing you to go the next one.

For example, it's well-known that the water molecule:

- is neutral, so the zero-order term is zero
- has distinct barycenters for positive and negative charges so the first-order is non-zero

So first-order is enough. It's the usual dipolar model.

But for the CO$_2$ molecule, also neutral, its linear and symmetrical structure makes both barycenters coincide at the center of the molecule. So its dipolar momentum is zero, and you have to push to second order (quadripolar model) to describe it.

And so on.

Answer (score 1):

The multipole expansion is asymptotic (cf. my answer here: [The multipole expansion of electrostatic potential and large distances](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/707342/the-multipole-expansion-of-electrostatic-potential-and-large-distances/707354#707354)) and usually terms of higher order are much smaller than the leading one, which justifies truncation. The important thing is then which is the first non-vanishing term, which can be the monopole, dipole, quadrupole, octupole etc., cf. the answer by Miyase.