# Point dipole approximation limit

Tags: electromagnetism, dipole, magnetostatics

Can I approximate the field of a 10 mm length x 5 mm radius cylindrical magnet at 8 mm away using a point dipole approximation?

I was wondering if it would still be possible to create a semi-accurate approximation, even if it's too close to the magnet. If it's not possible, are there other simple alternatives available?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/707342/

Comment: @kricheli Your link provides only a qualitative answer. This question requires a quantitative one.

Comment: I doubt that the point dipole approximation will be “semi-accurate” that close in. You can evaluate the [relevant integrals](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MagneticFieldOfACylindricalBarMagnet/) numerically, assuming uniform magnetization. Each infinitesimal piece of the magnet is a dipole, and integration adds up their contributions.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 The fact that the parameter that is supposed to be small for the approximation to work is around 1 here does not count as a quantitative statement? :) You'd have to be *extremely* lucky for the approximation to work under those circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

The link I provided in the comment already relates to the fact that in your case you do not have a small parameter which you would normally need to make the dipole approximation work. $r/R$ (cf. [The multipole expansion of electrostatic potential and large distances](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/707342/the-multipole-expansion-of-electrostatic-potential-and-large-distances)) here is of the order 1, which is bad news.

If you want even more of a quantitative answer, you can plot the fields. I took some python script from the internet and modified it to produce this:
[image]

To explain: I have used a coil instead of a cylindrical magnet (field top left), and then I have used a smaller coil (factor 10) to simulate a dipole (and save me the work of using an actual one) (field top right).
If you plot their difference you see that the direction doesn't align too well (middle left), their difference (middle right) is a bit hard to read, so I've plotted the relative difference, i.e. the difference of the fields of coil and dipole divided by the absolute value of the coil's field (bottom left). You can see that where you intend to use the dipole approximation the relative difference can be pretty high. So better not use this approximation at those small distances.

The script (in case you want to fiddle with it):

```
# taken from https://magpylib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/examples_30_coil_field_lines.html and modified


import numpy as np
import magpylib as magpy

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

diameter=10
half_length=8
winding_number=16
factor=0.1


coil1 = magpy.Collection()
for z in np.linspace(-1*half_length, half_length, winding_number):
    winding = magpy.current.Loop(
        current=100,
        diameter=diameter,
        position=(0,0,z),
    )
    coil1.add(winding)

#uncomment if needed
#coil1.show()

coil2 = magpy.Collection()
for z in np.linspace(-1*factor*half_length, factor*half_length, winding_number):
    winding = magpy.current.Loop(
        current=100/factor**2,
        diameter=diameter*factor,
        position=(0,0,z),
    )
    coil2.add(winding)

#uncomment if needed
#coil2.show()


fig, [[ax1,ax2], [ax3,ax4], [ax5,ax6]] = plt.subplots(3, 2, figsize=(13,20))

# create grid
ts = np.linspace(-20, 20, 20)
grid = np.array([[(x,0,z) for x in ts] for z in ts])

# compute and plot field of coil1
B = magpy.getB(coil1, grid)
Bamp = np.linalg.norm(B, axis=2)
Bamp /= np.amax(Bamp)

sp = ax1.streamplot(
    grid[:,:,0], grid[:,:,2], B[:,:,0], B[:,:,2],
    density=2,
    color=Bamp,
    linewidth=np.sqrt(Bamp)*3,
    cmap='coolwarm',
)
ax3.streamplot(
    grid[:,:,0], grid[:,:,2], B[:,:,0], B[:,:,2],
    density=2,
    color='blue',
)

# compute and plot field of coil2
B = magpy.getB(coil2, grid)
Bamp = np.linalg.norm(B, axis=2)
Bamp /= np.amax(Bamp)

cp = ax2.contourf(
    grid[:,:,0], grid[:,:,2], Bamp,
    levels=100,
    cmap='coolwarm',
)
ax2.streamplot(
    grid[:,:,0], grid[:,:,2], B[:,:,0], B[:,:,2],
    density=2,
    color='black',
)
ax3.streamplot(
    grid[:,:,0], grid[:,:,2], B[:,:,0], B[:,:,2],
    density=2,
    color='red',
)

# compute and plot field of difference
B = magpy.getB(coil1, grid) - magpy.getB(coil2, grid)
Bamp = np.linalg.norm(B, axis=2)
Bamp /= np.amax(Bamp)

#sp2 = ax4.streamplot(
#    grid[:,:,0], grid[:,:,2], B[:,:,0], B[:,:,2],
#    density=2,
#    color=Bamp,
#    linewidth=np.sqrt(Bamp)*3,
#    cmap='coolwarm',
#)
cp2 = ax4.contourf(
    grid[:,:,0], grid[:,:,2], Bamp,
    levels=100,
    cmap='coolwarm',
)
ax4.streamplot(
    grid[:,:,0], grid[:,:,2], B[:,:,0], B[:,:,2],
    density=2,
    color='black',
)

# compute and plot field of difference
B = magpy.getB(coil1, grid) - magpy.getB(coil2, grid)
Breal = magpy.getB(coil1, grid)
Brealamp = np.linalg.norm(Breal, axis=2)
#B = np.divide(B, Brealamp) #B/Brealamp
Bamp = np.linalg.norm(B, axis=2)
Bamp = Bamp/Brealamp

#sp2 = ax4.streamplot(
#    grid[:,:,0], grid[:,:,2], B[:,:,0], B[:,:,2],
#    density=2,
#    color=Bamp,
#    linewidth=np.sqrt(Bamp)*3,
#    cmap='coolwarm',
#)
levels=np.linspace(0,2,100)
cp3 = ax5.contourf(
    grid[:,:,0], grid[:,:,2], Bamp,
    levels=levels,
    cmap='coolwarm',
)
ax5.streamplot(
    grid[:,:,0], grid[:,:,2], B[:,:,0], B[:,:,2],
    density=2,
    color='black',
)


# figure styling
ax1.set(
    title='Magnetic field of coil1',
    xlabel='x-position [mm]',
    ylabel='z-position [mm]',
    aspect=1,
)
ax2.set(
    title='Magnetic field of coil2',
    xlabel='x-position [mm]',
    ylabel='z-position [mm]',
    aspect=1,
)
ax3.set(
    title='Magnetic fields (directions) compared',
    xlabel='x-position [mm]',
    ylabel='z-position [mm]',
    aspect=1,
)
ax4.set(
    title='Magnetic field difference',
    xlabel='x-position [mm]',
    ylabel='z-position [mm]',
    aspect=1,
)
ax5.set(
    title='Magnetic field difference (relative)',
    xlabel='x-position [mm]',
    ylabel='z-position [mm]',
    aspect=1,
)

plt.colorbar(sp.lines, ax=ax1, label='[mT]')
plt.colorbar(cp, ax=ax2, label='[mT]')
#plt.colorbar(sp2.lines, ax=ax4, label='[mT]')
plt.colorbar(cp2, ax=ax4, label='[mT]')
plt.colorbar(cp3, ax=ax5, label='')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```